# Angular one: javascript timeout function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, count, timeout

I'm trying to call a function based on an input value.
The scenario will: if nobody will add something in that input for 10 seconds (so the value will be null), make that input disabled.
I would like to use ng-change or something similar from angular methods instead of any "keyboard key" conditions.

Now the first think to do is to set timer to 0 when the button is clicked and counting to 10.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.count = 10;
  $scope.inpValue = '';

  function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if ($scope.inpValue.length === 0 && $scope.count >= 10) {
        alert("Execute function when if is true");
      }
    }, 1000);
  };
  myFunction();

}]);
```

**[JSFIDDLE:](https://jsfiddle.net/7ttvcs8x/2/)**

Comment: This doesn't address your problem but: In angularjs, you should use the $timeout service instead of setTimeout. Angularjs's change detection doesn't work correctly unless you do so. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: What's the purpose of the button `Close when it reaches 10` in the fiddle?

Comment: @Sajal That should call the function on click, basically I can call myFunction on input change using ng-change or on that button using ng-click. Is one or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the problem statement is ambiguous, this is probably what you require.

- If no value is entered in the `input` box, it will disable in 10 seconds.
- If the value is changed, the timer `resets` to default and re runs.
- `Close on 10` button also resets the timer but button gets `disabled` once clicked. It only gets `enabled` when the value of the `input` box changes.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.count = 1;
  $scope.inpValue = "";
  $scope.disableInput = false;
  $scope.disableBtn = false;

  $scope.checkToDisable = function() {
    console.log($scope.count);

    $scope.customTimeout = $timeout(function() {
      if ($scope.inpValue.length === 0 && $scope.count == 10) {
        $scope.count = 0;
        $scope.disableInput = true;
        $scope.disableBtn = true;
        $timeout.cancel($scope.customTimeout);
      } else {
        $scope.count++;
        $scope.checkToDisable();
        if ($scope.count > 10) {
          $timeout.cancel($scope.customTimeout);
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
  };

  $scope.resetTimer = function() {
    $scope.count = 1;
    $timeout.cancel($scope.customTimeout);
    $scope.checkToDisable();
  };

  $scope.checkToDisable();

}]);
```

```css
button {
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 4px red;
}

button:active {
  background: orange;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type='text' ng-model="inpValue" ng-change="resetTimer(); disableBtn = false;" ng-disabled="disableInput" />
    <button ng-click="resetTimer(); disableBtn = true;" ng-disabled="disableBtn">Close when it reaches 10</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: yes, something like that, need also to stop the counter after the input has a value but I can deal with that :) ty

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that maybe is useful for you to continue:

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type='text' ng-model="inpValue" placeholder='Something here' ng-change="myFunction()" />
    <button>Close when it reaches 10
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) 
{
  $scope.count = 10;
  $scope.inpValue = '';

  function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if ($scope.inpValue.length === 0 && $scope.count >= 10) {
        alert("Execute function when if is true");
      }
    }, 10000);
  };
  myFunction();

}]);
```

Full sample: https://jsfiddle.net/Lv2Lb1a6/1/